# Reading file to list of lists using Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to read a text file using Common Lisp. File must be read to list of lists. Each list in the list must consist of a line from file.

Now, I have done such code:

```
(with-open-file (in file)
  (loop for line = (read-line in nil nil)
        while line
        collect (coerce line 'list)))
```

But, for example, the rusult looks as: ((#\0 #\0 #\0) (#\1 #\0 #\1)). But I need to have result without #\ characters: ((0 0 0) (1 0 1)). How to fix it?

Comment: What is in the file? As I see, you got what you wanted - list of lists, each list includes your characters. If you want, you can covert characters to integets, but it is "list of lists" now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already converting the line to a list of characters;
all you need to do is convert the characters to numbers:

```
(with-open-file (in file)
  (loop for line = (read-line in nil nil)
    while line
    collect (map 'list #'digit-char-p line)))
```

You can also use `(parse-integer (string c))` instead of [`digit-char-p`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_digi_1.htm), but that seems an overkill.